# method to check if a binary search tree is balanced

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a method that checks whether a given binary search tree is balanced or not within a given tolerance. This is the code that I have so far. I have no ideas further than this. Whoever answers this question, could you please provide an explanation as well? That would be very helpful thank you.

A balanced tree is balanced if for each node in the tree the depth of each nodes children differs by at most some tolerance. given a link BinaryTreeNode and a tolerance, it returns true if root is balanced and false otherwise.

tolerance is the maximum tolerance to decide if the tree is balanced

it returns true if the tree is balanced and false if it is not.
I want it to throw a nullpointerexception if root is == null
and an illegalargumentexception if tolerance is < 0

The problem with my code is that the line

```
if(computeHeight(root) == -1){
```

the type computeHeight is not applicable for the arguments

I have a getDepth() method that returns the level that the node is located on

```
public <T> boolean isBalanced(BinaryTreeNode<T> root, int tolerance) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(root == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if(tolerance < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if(computeHeight(root) == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
public int computeHeight(BinaryTreeNode<T> root){
    if(root == null){
        return 0;
    }
    int leftHeight = computeHeight(root.getLeftChild());
    if(leftHeight == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    int rightHeight = computeHeight(root.getRightChild());
    if(rightHeight == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    int heightDifference = Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight);
    if(heightDifference > 1){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But can you state what logic you wish to use to test the balance? Tell us more about how you will know when a tree is balanced or not. Then say why this code does not work. Then we can point you in the right direction. As it is you are simply asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: I edited it to provide a more in depth description of what it is that I'm trying to do.